# Navigation Issues Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I have this unusual issues to navigate in Windows Phone 8.1

Here is my code :

```
try
{
    news c = news_List.SelectedItem as news;
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.newsItem), c);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageDialog j = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
    await j.ShowAsync();
}
```

So the problem is for Windows Phone 8.1, sometimes when I click on the element the application crash, and that's it nothing else. 
On debug mode nothing appends, and on Windows 
10 Mobile it works like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
try
{
    news c = news_List.SelectedItem as news;
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.newsItem), c));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageDialog j = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
    await j.ShowAsync();
}
```

and don't forget to add async in the method and make sure that you are getting the data on another page.

Comment: Works well ! Thanks a lot! 
Can you explain why ?

Comment: The most probable cause is that may be you were trying to call Navigate from a **Non UI** thread.For Non UI Thread simply use Dispatcher.RunAsync() method to dispatch the code on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

use
`news c = news_List.SelectedItem as news;
Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageName),c);`

Comment: That doesn't allow him to pass any data to the new view, though